# Flutter is not showing color palletes in Visual Studio Code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio to code in Flutter, when I first started Flutter on VS Code, it was showing color palettes for each color whenever I used to hover the mouse over the color name in the code `Colors.yellow`, but after a day it suddenly stopped showing the color palette for any color.

First it used to show like this

[image: First]

Now it just shows it like this instead of showing the color palette

[image: Now]

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: RadialGradient(colors: [
                Colors.yellow,
                Colors.red,
                
              ]),
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to write the color 1st, then you will find color box and while hovering over the color box, you will get color picker.

While writing color

[image]

if you can't find while writing, press `ctrl+space` key.

After writing color name

[image]

You can read the [Color Picker for Flutter's Color(s) similar to CSS](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3240)

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried pressing `ctrl + space` while writing the color, then the entire color palette started appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i found. When input color, the color preview is collapsed by default.  Click your mouse on the arrow to expand it. The color pallete will show automatically.

[image: color palletes is collapsed]

It also works for `Icons` when input `Icons.xxx` but cannot preview it.

[image: Preview icon]